# How to store RealityKit types like ModelEntity, Entity or Materials on the device?

Tags: ios, swift, arkit, realitykit

I have a class that looks like this:

```
enum EntityState {
    case unselected
    case selected
    case colored
}

class AREntity {
    var entity: ModelEntity
    var state: EntityState
    var notes: String
    var originalMaterial: PhysicallyBasedMaterial
    var isHidden: Bool
    var isFaded: Bool
    var isFadedOthers: Bool
    var isolated: Bool
    var isIsolated: Bool
    ...
}
```

So this class has properties with types like ModelEntity, enum, PhysicallyBasedMaterial and the user can change the entitys material, opacity and so on. But I want the device to store the modified entity so when the user opens the application again and uses the same entity, the modifications would remain. I was thinking of UserDefaults but it only allows a short list of types to store and ModelEntity or Materials are not among them.